# Quickbooks Employee update through web connector 2.1.0.31 issue

Tags: quickbooks

I have issue with adding / updating employees through php soap to quickbooks enterprise solution 2016 via quickbooks web connector 2.1.0.30.

Outgoing XML request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
        <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                <EmployeeModRq requestID="102">
                    <EmployeeMod>
                        <ListID>80000013-1481963705</ListID>
                        <EditSequence>1482221410</EditSequence>
                        <Name>NewEmployee3 J Profile</Name>
                        <FirstName>NewEmployee3</FirstName>
                        <MiddleName>J</MiddleName>
                        <LastName>Profile</LastName>
                        <EmployeeAddress>
                            <Addr1>test street</Addr1>
                            <Addr2>Sivakasi</Addr2>
                            <City>Houston</City>
                            <State>TX</State>
                            <PostalCode>77497</PostalCode>
                        </EmployeeAddress>
                        <SSN>2342342345</SSN>
                    </EmployeeMod>
                </EmployeeModRq>
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>
```

When i pass SSN, mobile or hired date after employee address, i am getting error

0x80040400: QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream.

Can you please tell me how to add

SSN, HiredDate, Mobile, payroll deduction values and DirectDeposit bank account information

FYI, I am using Quickbooks Web Connector 2.1.0.30 & Quickbooks Enterprise Solution 2016

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you get this error:

> 0x80040400: QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream.

The first thing you should do is run to the `XML Validator` tool that is *included with the QuickBooks SDK*.

If you haven't done that already, please do it. It will tell you *exactly* where the error is.

In your case, you'll find out that `Name` and `SSN` are not valid fields.

You should also consider:

- Using a different version of qbXML. qbXML 2.0 is 15+ years old now. Use the highest version your QuickBooks supports. If you're not sure what version your QuickBooks supports, refer to the QuickBooks documentation or search Google.
- Referring to the QuickBooks OSR for field reference about which fields are supported, and in what order you should put them in your request.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you send script how to validate my qbxml? 
And also send EmployeeAdd and EmployeeMod valid field tags?
Current qbxml version is 13.0? 
What is the right version to pass quickbooks webconnector 2.1.0.30 to quickbooks enterprise solution 2016.

Comment: As I indicated above, please use the XML VALIDATOR tool included with the QuickBooks SDK to validate your qbXML. Likewise, use the QuickBooks OSR to view what the valid fields/tags are.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response. Can you send script how to validate my qbxml? 
And also send EmployeeAdd and EmployeeMod valid field tags?
Current qbxml version is 13.0? 
What is the right version to pass quickbooks webconnector 2.1.0.30 to quickbooks enterprise solution 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Find out the issues and fixed the employee creation.

Now I had one more issue. I want to add marital status and employee federal state tax configuration with number of allowances. Is it possible to update payroll information with tax options.

I was checked out in OSR also, there is no options for that. Can you please guide for me.